# how can i solve abnormal predict?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

The difference between the last value and the next predicted value is very large.

here is my model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(None, 1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(None, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))


model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.summary()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=2, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

and I want to know next time series So, I did

[image: a busy cat]

`y_test[-1]` and  predicted `lastY` gap is too large

am I wrong? or something error code?

I do not know why this happened.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a programming problem.

Comment: maybe your `lastX` is some outlier condition, check for that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of predicting on x, you're predicting on y.

Shouldn't `last_X = x_test[-1]` instead of `last_X = y_test[-1]` ?

Comment: I think it's because LSTM's prediction depends on the previous values. Since you're giving a single value to the LSTM model, it might not be that accurate. Instead, try giving the last 10 values or so.

Comment: same problem... i think that's not fundamental solution